# user roles based access control and permissions in reactjs using aws serverless framework

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, user-management, role-based-access-control

I want to create a user management page using reactjs,mui and aws serverless framework. For that I want to include the User Role based Access control(Give the access to the admin to change the access control and permission for the users) , permissions and want to give the access to the admin to change the role for a particular user. OR that what should I want to do? Is there any specific ways are there in aws to do this task?

I am a newbie for this web development. and I tried to find out the correct way to find the solution but I didn't find yet.